# Why my rendered video Is impossible to be opened?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video

I rendered a video, 60fps, 1920px X 1080px High output quality and format ffmpeg in mpeg-4 using cycles. After the rendering process i been able to open the file just once. Once i closed the video the file just size reduced at like 0kb so the file is impossible ti be opened. What should i do?

Comment: Sounds like some type of OS, file system or drive failure occurred if you were able to open it once.  Back up data

Comment: Did you by any chance re-render the same scene and then stopped the renderingprocess in the middle of it? I made that mistake before and got the same as you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering an animation sequence in mpeg-4 format is not adviseable. This is because if there's an error in the middle of process, the entire render time you've spent will be lost without nothing to back them up.

Thus, I would simply advise you not to do that. Stick with the PNG file format for the rendering. Once it's finished, then you can compile them into a video with 3rd party video editing software, like Adobe Premiere Pro. In Adobe Premiere Pro, you'd only need to import with the 'image sequence' checked on, pick the first image (the one which ends with 000 extension), and only then export it into an mpeg-4 format, or any other format. Voila, you just got an animation sequence.

This way, you now do have some solid backup, that is the entire stack of images (based on your setting, 60 images per second of animation) in your folder. So should you get an error when you try to compile them in Premiere Pro, you now still have the 'raw' images, which you can then rework with.

If you don't currently have Premiere Pro, that's okay. Most other video editing software, free and paid, can usulaly do this as well, with a slightly different ways. Just google 'image sequence to video (the video editing software you have)', and I believe you'll find it as easy to do and follow.

Comment: You can of course import your png file sequence into Blender's video sequencer and save that to Mpeg format. No need to use external software. For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgab9VC_laQ